# Can't get Youtube access token with curl (PHP)

Tags: php, api, curl, authentication, youtube

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#OAuth2_Server_Side_Web_Applications_Flow) guide to make a server side Youtube web app in PHP. I can't get past step 4. Everything up to that is good, it redirects to my script and I can obtain the authorization code no problem. However, when I try to exchange that code for an authorization token (as demonstrated in step 4), absolutely NOTHING happens. I can't find any errors, just nothing happens on my browser. My PHP script is this (private info removed):

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'code' => $_GET['code'],
    'client_id' => '[REMOVED]',
    'client_secret' => '[REMOVED]',
    'redirect_uri' => '[REMOVED]',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $return;

?>
```

Maybe I'm just way over my head here, but can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

after `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

Comment: Awesome, now I'm getting something. It's giving me this error: { "error" : "invalid_grant" } ...This is weird because I just used the grant_type the Youtube API docs said to. Thanks for the help though, I'll see if I can find something to fix this new problem...

Comment: @FramesPerSushi check this:: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication  scroll to bottom where you see "Invalid Grant", hope that helps solving the issue

Comment: Thanks. The problem was I was testing by refreshing the same page where I had logged in an hour ago. The authorization code had expired. It's all good now.